# Exclude Subproject commit Git

Tags: git, git-submodules

How can I exclude `Subproject commit ....` I changed nothing in the submodule, only pull changes from remote repository! I think I commited something unneeded in the main repository, when created submodule. Any ideas?

1) When I created submodule **git diff** in main repository also showed

```
submodule-path:
    Subproject commit 5a8162ff9a602deb96956854346988e1ee45672e
```

and I commited this

2) then someone commited to submodule, so it has the following log

```
2ff89a2bfcaa0 last commit
5a8162ff9a602d  first commit
```

3) I updated submodule with

`git submodule update --remote --merge`

4) now **git status** shows

```
modified:   submodule-path (new commits)
```

But I changed nothing in the submodule, only pull last remote changes! And I need this last changes

**git diff** shows

```
diff --git a/submodule-path b/submodule-path
index 5a8162f..2ff89a2 160000
--- a/submodule-path
+++ b/submodule-path
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit 5a8162ff9a602deb96956854346988e1ee45672e
+Subproject commit 2ff89a2bfcaa014885a70b0da86e997ecd8d0688
```

Comment: "Pull" means "run fetch, then run merge". Merge may well (and in this case did) change something. You almost certainly *want* to change something, too. What you need to know is what changes you want to make, and where and how to make them. We (StackOverflow) can tell you how to manipulate submodules in various ways, but we cannot tell you what changes you *want* to make.

Comment: below @oktapodia suggests `git submodule update -f --init`, but it resets to first commit, but I need the last.

Comment: The default `update` subcommand just forces the submodule back to the commit recorded in the superproject. But there isn't necessarily a single "last" commit in *any* Git repository. I'll write something up, but remember, submodules are inherently complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update:

This is NOT an error. The submodules just work in this way.

The main repo doesn't track the submodule's files. It only tracks the submodule's url and commit id (**the submodule's state at a specific point**).

[Quote from Starting with Submodules in book *Pro Git*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

> Although sbmodule `DbConnector` is a subdirectory in your working directory, Git sees it as a submodule and doesn’t track its contents when you’re not in that directory. Instead, Git sees it as a **particular commit from that repository**.

Since you updated the module with `git submodule update`, you have to stage the change (in fact, the updated commit id). If you don't wanna update the tracking of submodules, just don't use `git submodule update` at the beginning, or just discard the change.

---

It's very likely that the submodule is HEAD detached. Go in the submodule, reset the submodule to fix the HEAD detached status.

```sh
# Do this in the submodule
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Then update the submodule to the latest commit.

```sh
# run in the project's root, not the submodule's
git submodule update --remote --merge
```

Comment: yes, it was detached, but nope, still see `modified:   submodule-path (new commits)` =( What did: 1) go to submodule dir, 2) `git checkout master`, 3) `git reset --hard origin/master`4) in projects root `git submodule update --remote --merge`

Comment: @IvanKush The submodules just work in this way. The main repo doesn't track the submodule's files. It only tracks the submodule's url and commit id (the state at a specific time). Since your updated the module with `git submodule update`, you have to stage the change (in fact, the updated commit id).

Comment: @IvanKush Updated my answer explaining how the submodule works.

Answer (score 3):

First, let's try to make some things here clear.  It's hard because when you work with Git on your own, it's complicated.  When you add a second Git repository–to which you `git push` your own commits, and from which you `git fetch` other people's new commits—*that* is complicated too.  A submodule is nothing more than a *third* Git repository, and that third Git repository has a *fourth* Git repository to which you might perhaps `git push` your own commits, and from which you might `git fetch` other people's new commits.  So we're leaping right into a situation in which there are at least *four* Git repositories, all of which are somewhat independent of each other.

We could try to draw pictures but even pictures will be a bit muddy.  How do we keep *four* repositories straight?  Git has names for two of them: the two that you work with directly, yourself.  One is the *superproject*, which is where you are running `git diff` and seeing:

> ```
> diff --git a/submodule-path b/submodule-path
> index 5a8162f..2ff89a2 160000
> --- a/submodule-path
> +++ b/submodule-path
> @@ -1 +1 @@
> -Subproject commit 5a8162ff9a602deb96956854346988e1ee45672e
> +Subproject commit 2ff89a2bfcaa014885a70b0da86e997ecd8d0688
> ```

The other is the submodule itself: if you `cd submodule-path` and run various Git commands, you'll see that it is an ordinary Git repository.  The only thing unusual about it is that it is almost always in "detached HEAD" mode.

Your superproject Git probably has an `origin`.  That's a repository—well, technically, a short name you can use in this Git to *refer to* another repository—to which you can `git push` commits you make in the superproject.  You *will* need to make a commit in the superproject and then `git push` this new commit to `origin`.  What precisely goes into this superproject commit?  We'll see in a moment.

Your submodule Git *also* has an `origin`.  That's a *different* other Git repository: the fourth Git in this not-very-well-drawn-at-all picture.  It's not clear to me whether you want to send commits to that fourth repository.  You *do* presumably want to *get* a commit *from* that repository.  There are multiple ways to go about this, including using `git submodule update --remote`, perhaps with additional options.  I prefer to just `cd submodule-path` and start working *directly in the submodule Git* as this reduces the problem to things you already know how to do: manipulate one local Git repository based on new commits that have appeared in its `origin`.

#### Supposing you just want to pick up some new commit(s) in the submodule

If this is the case, you can:

```
cd submodule-path           # begin working in your submodule
git fetch                   # update origin/*
git checkout origin/master  # get a detached HEAD on the desired commit
                            # (this assumes `origin/master` is the
                            # desired commit; it's impossible for me
                            # to know which commit you desire)
```

and now the submodule has the desired commit as its detached HEAD.  There is nothing to `git push` from here: all the commits that reside in this repository are commits obtained from this submodule's `origin`'s Git.

(Using `git submodule update --remote` may do the `cd submodue-path` and `git fetch` and `git checkout origin/master` for you, all without changing your own working directory.  The whole operation runs in its own sub-shell so that none of these `cd` operations affect where you are.  That seems to be what your `git submodule update --remote --merge` did: there was no need to make a new merge commit, so it just switched to the commit identified by some branch name on `origin`.)

#### But if you need to make new commits in the submodule ...

In this case, you *may* want to force the submodule to be on a branch, so that you're working in a more normal work-flow.  Then you'd probably want to `git checkout master` for instance, and then do various commands.  Eventually you might end up with a new commit made in your submodule repository, which you will need to `git push` to the `origin` repository *of* the submodule, so that other people will be able to obtain this commit too.

You can leave the submodule on its branch.  The submodule's branch is irrelevant to the superproject Git: the superproject Git cares only which *commit* is checked out in the submodule.  (That's why in the earlier case above, we can just switch the detached HEAD around.)

#### Now that the submodule Git is on the right commit, you must make a new superproject commit

At this point, you can `cd` back out of the submodule into the superproject.  You'll see in `git diff` output something exactly like you quoted above, and `git status` will say:

> ```
> modified:   submodule-path (new commits)
> ```

This doesn't necessarily mean there are any *new* commits in the submodule repository that aren't in the submodule repository's `origin`.  It just means that the submodule repository is on (as its HEAD, detached or not) a commit that is not the commit that the current superproject status says it *should* be on.

The problem here is that the current superproject commit is, in a way, defective.  It *was* correct, but it isn't any more, just as the current superproject commit would be defective if you had, say, edited the file `README.md` locally.  This means that you need to make, *in the superproject*, a new, corrected commit.  The superproject Git will make the new commit from whatever is in the index of the superproject repository, so you now need to update the index.

If you'd changed a `README.md` file, the way you'd update the index is:

```
git add README.md
```

But what you changed was not a `README.md` file.  It was, instead, the submodule hash ID.  So you need to record the new hash ID in the index.  The way you do that is:

```
git add submodule-path
```

This takes the hash ID from the submodule by running `cd submodule-path; git rev-parse HEAD` to gets the raw hash ID—the one that showed up in the `git diff`—and stuff that hash ID into the index.  Now `git diff`—which compares the index to your work-tree—*won't* show these `Subproject commit` lines any more, but `git diff --cached`—which compares the current (superproject) commit to the index—*will* show them.  Now `git status` will say that these "new commits" are ready to be committed, rather than not-yet-staged-for-commit.

You can `git add` any other superproject files (if there are any that need to be updated in the index) at this time.  Then:

```
git commit
```

in the superproject will make a new commit that will record the hash ID you put into the superproject's index when you ran `git add` on the submodule path.

#### You're (locally) done with the update, but here's some things to think about

Note that *every* commit in the superproject records the hash ID in the submodule.  Every time you `git checkout` a different superproject commit, that not only extracts the right superproject files into the (superproject) index and your (superproject) work-tree, it also extracts the recorded submodule hash ID into the (superproject) index.  It *does not*, by default, `cd` into the submodule and `git checkout` that particular commit by its hash ID.  You can change this with a setting, or add `--recursive` to `git checkout`; or you can just run `git submodule update`, which tells your Git to `cd` into each submodule, one at a time, and `git checkout` the hash ID currently recorded in the (superproject) index.

You will, at some point, need to `git push` the new commit you made in your superproject, to the `origin` (of the superproject), so that the new commit with its newly recorded hash ID appears in the Git over at the `origin` of your superproject.  You can do this whenever you like—but suppose you *did* make new commits *in* your submodule, and you have not yet used `git push` in the submodule itself to send those new commits to the `origin` of the submodule.  In this case, the new commit you made in the superproject records the hash ID of a commit that *only exists in your local submodule repository*.  If someone runs `git fetch` to the superproject Git's `origin`, they'll get this new hash ID from the new commit you sent, but not be able to *find* that commit in *their* clone of the submodule.  So if you did make new submodule commits, it's usually best to `git push` them first, *then* `git push` the new superproject commits.

(If you did not make any new submodule commits, there's no problem here.)

Answer (score 1):

Running the command `git submodule update -f --init` should resolve your issue, this will reset your submodule to the remote `HEAD`

Comment: nope. It resets to prev submodule commit
`5a8162ff9a60`. But the last commit is `2ff89a2bfcaa0`. I need the last

Comment: You have to run this command from the git directory, not from the submodule directory

Comment: yes, I ran it from base dir. Also this command makes detached  submodule branch

Comment: I had the same problem as the original poster and this is the only answer that worked for me !!