# Git ignore submodule files

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have created a local git repo, let's call it 'aaa' for the moment. I have then added a submodule in 'aaa' which is located in the folder aaa/Projects/bbb/Code.

Every time I edit a file in the submodule i.e. Code it adds the changes to the original repo waiting for a commit.

How do I ignore the folder 'Code'?

I've tried updating the original git repo with the following without success.

```
git config submodule.bbb.active false
```

and

```
git config submodule.bbb.ignore all
```

But neither work, as soon as I update a file in 'Code' it add the changes as normal.

What am I doing wrong?

Previous posts from 2019 show that `git config submodule.bbb.ignore all` should work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude Subproject commit Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58170570/exclude-subproject-commit-git)

Comment: "**Now that the submodule Git is on the right commit, you must make a new superproject commit** … It just means that the submodule repository is on (as its HEAD, detached or not) a commit that is not the commit that the current superproject status says it should be on." — @torek

Comment: Thank you but I think I'm more confused than before. Just started with git and I'm starting to lose concentration. So from what I can work out is that the submodule should show in the main repo, is that right? If so I don't like it, I find t confusing and I just want to keep them separated.

Comment: Basically the main repo will hold everything for my client, contracts, approvals, colour swatches , fonts etc. I then want to setup submodules for jobs i.e. website, business stationery, marketing etc. The reason for the submodule is so that if the job requires code, I can use a remote repo and keep everything separated. I did just think about having a main Git repo and then having a separate git repo for the job. I can then just add the job to a gitignore file. This seems the best scenario but I was told this is what a gitmodule is and I should use that.